# get segmentation fault when I try to use tbb to parallel my program

Tags: c++, opencv, tbb

My program works fine in serial way, but get segmentation fault when I try to use tbb to parallelize it.

I'm a tbb green hand.My program is quiet simple but I can't figure out why it went wrong. I wish I could get some help here. Below is my program.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <tbb/tbb.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
class test{
public:
    Mat * imgarr;
    test(){
        imgarr = new Mat[10];
        for(int i =0 ;i<10;i++){
            imgarr[i] = Mat::zeros(10,10,CV_64F);
        }
    }
    void add(int i) const {
        Mat& tmp = imgarr[i];
        tmp(Range(0,10),Range(0,10)) += 1;
    }
    void operator()(tbb::blocked_range<int>& r) const {
        for(int i = r.begin();i != r.end();i++){
            add(i);
        }
    }
    ~test(){
        delete[] imgarr;
    }

};
int main(){
    test a;
    tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0,10), a);
    for(int i =0 ;i< 3;i++){
        cout << a.imgarr[0]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. 
Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @liakoyras I’m sorry I don’t show too much useful info in my question and I will pay more attention to the community rules.But I think my snippet is reproducible enough and compact enough for anyone who has tbb experience to tell what goes wrong. I don’t want to give you such impression that “I always ask help first before I get my hands dirty”. I actually solved this problem by myself before I get any useful advice, which you can confirm by checking my [GitHub commit history](https://github.com/xichangzun/radial_voting). I thought it would be more complex.I will be more cautious next time.

Comment: Don't worry, it's all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tbb::parallel_for` creates multiple copies of the supplied body object. Since you have not provided any copy constructor for `class test`, the default one will just copy the state, i.e. the `imgarr` pointer. Then, once a temporary `test` object created by TBB is destroyed, `imgarr` is released and you cannot work with it anymore.

Try using `std::shared_ptr` for `imgarr`.

Comment: thanks for your help, that’s exactly what happened.I solved the problem by replacing the imgarr outside the class.

Comment: You are welcome. And welcome to Stack Overflow! Here it is recommended to mark a proper answer accepted (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more details) - this way you help other SO users to find useful information quicker.